# Factory and Abstract Factory Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

How the factory pattern is using inheritance and abstract factory using composition to return a object to client?

I read head first design pattern book, that says above statement. But as per my understanding both are using inheritance.

Comment: It is impossible to guess what your question is. Be be more specific. Provide an example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract factory doesn't use composition.. it uses inheritance only.

Instance in Abstract factory returns a factory and from the desired class can be instantiated.

Abstract factory is just a layer above Factory design pattern..

To know more about composition Check java.io package in Java.

If a FileReader class needs to be instantiated a File Object is mandatory.

like new FileReader(new File("")).

This is known as composition and it is no where used in Abstract factory

Answer (score 1):

**Factory Pattern** defines an interface for creating objects and lets subclasses decide which objects to be created **(inheritence)**. this way client only needs to know the abstract type they are using.

Abstract Factory provides abstract type for creating family of products. Subclasses of this type define how these products are produced. The product subclasses create parallel sets of product families.**(composition)**.

Comment: Can you give an example for more clarification?

Comment: You better refer to Head First Design Patterns Book. They got lots of examples, explaining this